# Ways to Pause/Resume a Process with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, wallpaper

First im Sorry for my Bad English.

I try to pause and resume a .exe File with Python. I Already tryed psutil.Process(...).suspend()/.resume() but this take more then 8 Seconds.
Normally thats okay, but i freeze a WallpaperEngine and it looks very shit if your Background is Freezed. So i need a alternative for p.suspend() and p.resume().

Important Informations:
-> OS: Windows 10
-> Python: 3.8

My Code:

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
import win32gui
import time
import pygetwindow as gw
import psutil

process_name = "WallEngine"
pid = None
detectedPIDs = 0

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if process_name in proc.name():
        pid = proc.pid
        detectedPIDs+=1
        print(pid)

if detectedPIDs == 1:
    pass
else:
    print("Didnt Found the WallEngine Process. Enter Searching Mode ...")
    while detectedPIDs != 1:
        for proc in psutil.process_iter():
            if process_name in proc.name():
                print("Searching Mode Finished. We Found!")
                pid = proc.pid
                detectedPIDs+=1
                print(pid)


print("[INFO] WallpaperEnginePerfomancer Booted.")

allWindows = []


def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx, currentlyPaused=None):
    if not win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        # print("Window isnt Visble yet! (" + str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)) + ")")
        pass
    else:
        rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
        windowName: str = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        x = rect[0]
        y = rect[1]
        w = rect[2] - x
        h = rect[3] - y
        currentScannedWindow = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(windowName)[0]
        if currentScannedWindow.isMaximized:
            if windowName == "" or windowName == None or "Paint 3D" in windowName:
                pass
            else:
                allWindows.append(windowName)


def window_handler():

    p = psutil.Process(pid)

    if len(allWindows) == 0:
        p.resume()
    else:
        p.suspend()

    allWindows.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None )
        window_handler()
        time.sleep(0.09)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewrite with using the `signal` library.

```
import signal

p = psutil.Process(pid)

if len(allWindows) == 0:
    signal.pause(p)
else:
    signal.pause(p)
```

Comment: First, Thank You for the Answer. I Think this works well on Linux but the Problem is that there not much Signal Options for Windows.